# How to split paired-end fastq files?

Tags: grep, bioinformatics, fastq, samtools

I have Illumina paired-end reads contained within one .fastq file, denoted as '/1' for forward reads and '/2' for reverse reads.

I am using grep to pull out the individual reads and place them into 2 respective files (one for forward reads and one for reverse.

```
grep -A 3 "/1$" sample21_pe.unmapped.fq > sample21_1_rfa.fq
grep -A 3 "/2$" sample21_pe.unmapped.fq > sample21_2_rfa.fq
```

However, when I try to use the files (fastqc, assembly, etc), they do not work. When running 
fastqc i get the following error:

```
 Failed to process file sample21_1_rfa.fq
 uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFormatException: ID line didn't start with '@'
     at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.readNext(FastQFile.java:134)
     at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.next(FastQFile.java:105)
     at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:76)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

But, if you look at the files they identifier does indeed start with an '@'. Any advice on why these files aren't working? I had originally converted .bam files into the .fastq files with

```
 samtools bam2fq
```

Here are samples of each individual file:

1. merged .fastq

```html
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1091:2161/1
GAGAAGCTCGTCCGGCTGGAGAATGTTGCGCTTGCGGTCCGGAGAGGACAGAAATTCGTTGATGTTAACGGTGCGCTCGCCGCGGACGCTCTTGATGGTGACGTCGGCGTTGAGCGTGACGCACG
+
B/</<//B<BFF<FFFFFF/BFFFFFFB<BFFF<B/7FFF7B/B/FF/F/<<F/FFBFFFBBFFFBFB/FF<BBB<B/B//BBFFFFFFF/B/FF/B77B//B7B7F/7F###############
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1091:2161/2
TGACGCCTGCCGTCAGGTAGGTTCTCCGCAGATCCGAAATCTCGCGACGCTCGGCGGCAACATCTGCCAGTCGTCCGTGGCGGGCGACGGTCTCGCGGCGTGCGTCACGCTCAACGCCGACGTAC
+
/B<B//F/F//B<///<FB/</F<<FFFFF<FFBF/FF<//FB/F//F7FBFFFF/B</7<F//<BB7/7BB7/B<F7BF<BFFFB7B#####################################
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1637:2053/1
NGTTTACCATACAACAATCTTGCGACCTATTCAAATCATCTATATGCCTTATCAAGTTTTCATAGCTTTCAAGATTCTCAATTTCCTCACGTCTCGCTTTGCTCAACCTACAAAAACTCTCTTCT
+
#<<BBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB/BFBBFBB<<<<FFFFFFBB<FBFFBFF
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1637:2053/2
TCGGTCGTTGGGAAAAGACCTGTGGTAAACATCCTACGCAAAAGCCATTGCGGTTACTCGTTCGTATGATTCTTGCATCAACTAATCAAGGCGATTGGGTTCTCGACCCATTTTGTGGAAGTTCG
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFB<FF<<BBFB
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1792:2218/1
TCTATCGGCTGACCGATAAGCTGTCGCCTGCCGACCGTCCTGCCATGGGACGGCGCATCGCACAGCTCACCCTGGACTAACTCTCCAACACCATGATGCTGACACGCTCGGCAAAAACACCCGAT
+
<<B/<B</FF/<B/<//F<//FF<<<FF//</7/F<</FFF####################################################################################
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1792:2218/2
TGCCGGAGGGCGTCGATGGTGGCATCGAGCTTTTTTGCCGAGCGTGTCAGCATGATGGTGTTGTAGAGATAGTCCATGGTGAGCTGTGCGATGCGCCGTTCCATGGCAGGACGGTCGGCAGGCGC
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFBFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFFBBFFFF/FF<F7FF//F/FBB/FFBFFF/F7BFF<F/FFFFFFFFB/7BB<7BFFFFFFFFFFFFF<B///B/7B/7/B//77BB//7B/B7/B#
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1903:2238/1
TATTCCAGCGACCGTTATAATCAAACTCAACTACATAGTCATTGCGGATTGCTTCAAGAAATTTTTTCCAGACTATTTCATCAATATTTATTTTGGGAACTGGTGCAACAGCAATTCTTTTTAAA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFF/FFBFFBFFFFFFFF/FFFFFF<<FFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBF/B/<B<B/FBF7/<FFFFFFF/BB/7///7FF<BFFF//B/FFF###
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1903:2238/2
TAAGGTTGGAGAAGCAACAATTTACCGTGATATTGATTTGCTCCGAACATATTTTCATGCGCCACTCGAGTTTGACAGGGAGAAAGGCGGGTATTATTATTTTAATGAAAAATGGGATTTTGCCC
+
B<BBBFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/BFFFFFFF<<FF<F<FFF/FF/FFFFBFB</<//<B/////<<FFFFB/<F<BFF/7/</7/7FB/B/BFF<//7BFF###############
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2107:2125/1
TGTAGTATTTATTACATCATATAGAATGTAGATATAAAAGATGAAAAAGCTATAATTTCTTTGATAATATAAGGAGGGAATAACACTATGAGGATTGATAGAGCAGGAATCGAGGATTTGCCGAT
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBFFFFFFFBB<FBB7BFF#
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2107:2125/2
TACCACTATCGGCAAATCCTCGATTCCTGCTCTATCAATCCTCATAGTGTTATTCCCTCCTTATATTATCAAAGAAATTATAGCTTTTTCATCTTTTATATCTACATTCTATATGATGTAATAAA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFFBF7F/B/BBF7/</FF/77F/77BB#
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2023:2224/1
TCACCAGCTCGGCACGCTTGTCCTTGACCTCCTGCTCGATCTGACCGTCCATCTTGGCTGCCACGGTGTTCTCCTCGGCGGAGTAGGCAAAGCAGCCCAGACGGTCGAACTGTATCTCCTTGACA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFB<<B7BBFBFFF<FFBBFFFBF/7B/<B<
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2023:2224/2
TCGAGGATCTGTGCAACTTTGTCAAGGAGATACAGTTCGACCGTCTGGGCTGCTTTGCCTACTCCGCCGAGGAGAACACCGTGGCAGCCAAGATGGACGGTCAGATCGAGCAGGAGGTCAAGGAC
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFFFF<7BF/<<BB###
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2038:2235/1
TTTATGCGAATGTAGAGTGGCTTCTCCACTGCCTCGGTGAAGCCCACGCGCGAGATGAGCGAATTAAGCTGCTTTGCAGTGAATTGCATTGCATATACACCTGCGTCGGCTTGAATACTTGTGCT
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFF//BFFFFFFFFFFFFF<B<BB###
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2038:2235/2
AATCCGCTCGTGAAAGCTCCCGATAACGCCACAGTGAACACCGTGGAGTTCTCTGATACCGAAGATTTCGCACGCAGCACAAGTATTCAAGCCGACGCAGGTGTATATGCAATGCAATTCACTGC
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2271:2041/1
NACACTTGTCGATGATCTTGCCAAGCTGCTTCTTGCCCACCAGGAAGCCGATCTCCAGATCAAACTCGTGGCCGGGAACACTCCGGTCCACAAAGCCCAGGTCCTGGGGAATGGGCTCATCGTAG
+
#<</BB/F/BB/F<FFFFFFFFF/<BFFFFFFFF<<FFBFFFFFFBFBFBBB<<FFFFBFFF/<B/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FB<<BFF77BFFF/<BFFFB<</BB</7BFFFB########
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2271:2041/2
GACTCATCTACAATGAGCCCATTCCCCAGGACCTGGGCTTTGTGGACCGGAGTGTTCCCGGCCACGAGTTTGATCTGGAGATCGGCTTCCTGGTGGGCAAGAAGCAGCTTGGCAAGATCATCGCC
+
<<BBBFFF<F/BFFFBFBF<BFF<<F/FFFBFFFF<<FFFFBFFFFFFBFFF/<B<F/<</<FFF//FFFFF/<<F/B/B/7/FF<<FF/7B/BBB/7///7////<B/B/BB/B/B/B/7BB##
```

2. Example of forward reads after being pulled out and placed into their own .fastq file:

```html
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1091:2161/1
GAGAAGCTCGTCCGGCTGGAGAATGTTGCGCTTGCGGTCCGGAGAGGACAGAAATTCGTTGATGTTAACGGTGCGCTCGCCGCGGACGCTCTTGATGGTGACGTCGGCGTTGAGCGTGACGCACG
+
B/</<//B<BFF<FFFFFF/BFFFFFFB<BFFF<B/7FFF7B/B/FF/F/<<F/FFBFFFBBFFFBFB/FF<BBB<B/B//BBFFFFFFF/B/FF/B77B//B7B7F/7F###############
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1637:2053/1
NGTTTACCATACAACAATCTTGCGACCTATTCAAATCATCTATATGCCTTATCAAGTTTTCATAGCTTTCAAGATTCTCAATTTCCTCACGTCTCGCTTTGCTCAACCTACAAAAACTCTCTTCT
+
#<<BBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB/BFBBFBB<<<<FFFFFFBB<FBFFBFF
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1792:2218/1
TCTATCGGCTGACCGATAAGCTGTCGCCTGCCGACCGTCCTGCCATGGGACGGCGCATCGCACAGCTCACCCTGGACTAACTCTCCAACACCATGATGCTGACACGCTCGGCAAAAACACCCGAT
+
<<B/<B</FF/<B/<//F<//FF<<<FF//</7/F<</FFF####################################################################################
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:1903:2238/1
TATTCCAGCGACCGTTATAATCAAACTCAACTACATAGTCATTGCGGATTGCTTCAAGAAATTTTTTCCAGACTATTTCATCAATATTTATTTTGGGAACTGGTGCAACAGCAATTCTTTTTAAA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFF/FFBFFBFFFFFFFF/FFFFFF<<FFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBF/B/<B<B/FBF7/<FFFFFFF/BB/7///7FF<BFFF//B/FFF###
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2107:2125/1
TGTAGTATTTATTACATCATATAGAATGTAGATATAAAAGATGAAAAAGCTATAATTTCTTTGATAATATAAGGAGGGAATAACACTATGAGGATTGATAGAGCAGGAATCGAGGATTTGCCGAT
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFF/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBFFFFFFFBB<FBB7BFF#
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2023:2224/1
TCACCAGCTCGGCACGCTTGTCCTTGACCTCCTGCTCGATCTGACCGTCCATCTTGGCTGCCACGGTGTTCTCCTCGGCGGAGTAGGCAAAGCAGCCCAGACGGTCGAACTGTATCTCCTTGACA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFB<<B7BBFBFFF<FFBBFFFBF/7B/<B<
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2038:2235/1
TTTATGCGAATGTAGAGTGGCTTCTCCACTGCCTCGGTGAAGCCCACGCGCGAGATGAGCGAATTAAGCTGCTTTGCAGTGAATTGCATTGCATATACACCTGCGTCGGCTTGAATACTTGTGCT
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFF//BFFFFFFFFFFFFF<B<BB###
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2271:2041/1
NACACTTGTCGATGATCTTGCCAAGCTGCTTCTTGCCCACCAGGAAGCCGATCTCCAGATCAAACTCGTGGCCGGGAACACTCCGGTCCACAAAGCCCAGGTCCTGGGGAATGGGCTCATCGTAG
+
#<</BB/F/BB/F<FFFFFFFFF/<BFFFFFFFF<<FFBFFFFFFBFBFBBB<<FFFFBFFF/<B/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FB<<BFF77BFFF/<BFFFB<</BB</7BFFFB########
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2678:2145/1
CTGTACATAGTACGTATTTGACGCCTGCGTCGATGTAGCGTTTGAGGAAGGGAAGCAGCGGTTCTGCAGAGTCCTCTTTCCATCCGTTGATGCTAATCATTCCGTTGCGTACATCCGCTCCGAGA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFF<FFF<FFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<BFFF7BFFFFFFFF<BBFFFFFFFFBBFBBB<FFBFFFFFFFFFFFFB<BFFFFFFBFB/BFFF####
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2972:2114/1
CTCTGTGCCGATCCCTTTGCCTTTGCGTTTTGAGGAAAGGAAACCACCTTCTGGGTCGGTGAGGATAGTTCCGGTGAAGGTGTTGTCCACCGCCAGGCATAGGGAATAGCTGTCAGCCTTTGCTC
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFB/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFBFFFF<FFFFFFFFFF<BFFFFF
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:2940:2222/1
CTAATTTTTTCATTATATTACTAATTTTGTAATTGGTAAAATATTATAATATCCTTGTACATTAAGACCCCAATAATCAGAAGAAGTAAAATTAATTCCTGCAACAGTTCTTAAATATCCATTAG
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/FBFBFFBFFFFF/<F<FFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFBFFFFFFFFF</FBFBBF<F/7//FFBFBBFFF/<7BF#
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:3037:2180/1
CGTCAGTTCCGCAACGATAAAGAGTTCCGCATTGCAGTCACCTGTACGCTGGTAGCCACCGGAACCGATGTCAAGCCGTTGGAGGTGGTGATGTTCATGCGCGACGTAGCTTCCGAGCCGTTATA
+
B/BBBBBFFFFFFF<FFBFFFFFF<FFFFBFFFFFFF<BBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFF/FFFFBFFBFFFFBFF/7F/BFB/BBFFFFFFFFBFF<BBF<7BBFFFFFFBBFFF/B#######
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:3334:2171/1
ACCGATGTACATACCCGGACGGGTACGCACATGCTCCATATCGCTCAAGTGGCGGATATTGTCATCTGTATATTCTACAGGTTGCTCCTGAGGGGTATTTGCCAGTTCTTCGGCAGCACCCTTTT
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFF</<BFFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFBF</BB///BF<FFFFF<</<B
--
@HISEQ:534:CB14TANXX:4:1101:3452:2185/1
CGCAGACGGATTTGCTTGAAGTCCGTCTCATCGTATTCCGACAACTCATCGAGGAACACACGCTTGTATTGACTGATACCCTTGATTTTCTCCGGGTCGTCAAGACCACTGAAATCAATCTTGCC
+
BBBBBFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFBFFBFFFFFFFFFB/77B/FBBFFF/<FFF/77BBFFFBFFBBB
--
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this operation is called `deinterlace fastq` or `deinterleave fastq`. The question already has the answer here:

deinterleave fastq file
https://www.biostars.org/p/141256/

I am copying it here, with minor reformatting for clarity:

```
paste - - - - - - - - < interleaved.fq \
    | tee >(cut -f 1-4 | tr "\t" "\n" > read1.fq) \
    |       cut -f 5-8 | tr "\t" "\n" > read2.fq
```

This command converts the interlaced fastq file into 8-column tsv file, cuts columns 1-4 (read 1 lines), changes from tsv to fastq format (by replacing tabs with newlines) and redirects the output to `read1.fq`. In the same STDOUT stream (for speed), using `tee`, it cuts columns 5-8 (read 2 lines), etc, and redirects the output to `read2.fq`.

You can also use **these command line tools**:

iamdelf/deinterlace: Deinterlaces paired-end FASTQ files into first and second strand files.
https://github.com/iamdelf/deinterlace

deinterleave FASTQ files
https://gist.github.com/nathanhaigh/3521724

Or online tools with Galaxy web UI, for example this tool: *"FASTQ splitter on joined paired end reads"*, installed on several public Galaxy instances, such as https://usegalaxy.org/ .

---

**Avoid using a regex** for simple fastq file parsing if you can use line numbers, both for speed (pattern matching is slower than simple counting) and for robustness.

Highly unlikely, but a pattern like `^@.*/1$` (or whatever the readers might change it to, while reusing this code later) can match also the base quality line. A good general rule is to simply rely on fastq spec, which says 4 lines per record.

Note that `@`, `/`, `1`, and `2` characters are allowed in Illumina Phred scores: https://support.illumina.com/help/BaseSpace_OLH_009008/Content/Source/Informatics/BS/QualityScoreEncoding_swBS.htm .

A one-liner that pulls out such (admittedly, very rare) reads is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: after reviewing the parsed files using grep, they were *slightly* different sizes. Using the above code worked smoothly, with both files being the exact same size. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, coming back to say.- when actually looking at the file, it is parsing both forward and reverse reads into both files. Im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: The input file may be corrupted, or not properly interleaved, such as some mate(s) could be missing. This would throw off the numbering. For example: `r1, r2, <missing r1>, r2, r1, r2, ...` .

Answer (score 1):

The fastq format uses 4 lines per read. 
Your snippet has 5, as there are `--` lines.  That could cause confusion to softwares expecting a 4 line format. 
You can add `--no-group-separator` to the grep call to avoid adding that separator.

I usually follow these steps to convert `bam` to `fastq.gz`

```
samtools bam2fq myBamfile.bam > myBamfile.fastq 

cat myBamfile.fastq | grep '^@.*/1$' -A 3 --no-group-separator > sample_1.fastq
cat myBamfile.fastq | grep '^@.*/2$' -A 3 --no-group-separator > sample_2.fastq 

gzip sample_1.fastq
gzip sample_1.fastq
```

Once you have the two files, you should order them to be sure that the reads are really paired.

Comment: You are right about the error source in OP's question. But I downvoted this answer because of the use of regexes to parse fastq files. Highly unlikely, but a pattern like this (or whatever the OP might change it to, while reusing this code) can match also the base quality line. A good general rule is to rely on fastq spec, which says 4 lines per record, and avoid pattern matching to find the read name lines.

Comment: @TimurShtatland thanks for pointing that out, but for Illumina reads, that pattern will only match the sequence identifier. I hope not to be mistaken, but `/`, `1`, and `2` are in the phred score only in Sanger sequencing. The probability of having a quality line that looks like `@....../1` or `@...../2` are null. I will double check though.

Answer (score 1):

We can split FASTQ files using Seqkit.

```
seqkit split2 -p 2 sample21_pe.unmapped.fq
```

https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#split2
Example 4 will help this question.

I'm not sure if it recognize the read ID. It split and write alternately into 1st-output-file and 2nd-output-file.