# Deinterleaving fastq file using Python code won't separate the lines correctly

Tags: python-3.x

Although there are solutions to this problem in other languages e.g.: [How to split paired-end fastq files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633038/how-to-split-paired-end-fastq-files), I need to implement it in Python, but my code won't correctly separate read1 and read2 lines from the interleaved.fq file into read1.fq and read2.fq files. I have tweaked different combinations of using indices and file.seek(0) usage, however, it has not worked.
Please note that a fastq contains 4 lines per read:

1. Read id : with /1, /2 at the end indicating read1 and read2
2. Sequence
3. Place holder line with either “+” or the Read id
4. Quality values in ascii characters

interleaved.fq file:

```
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
```

```
with open('interleaved.fq', 'r') as interleaved_file:
    lines = interleaved_file.readlines()
    num_lines = len(lines)
    interleaved_file.seek(0)
    with open('read1.fq', 'w') as read1_file, open('read2.fq', 'w') as read2_file:
        # Loop through the interleaved fastq file, reading 4 lines at a time
        for i in range(0, num_lines, 4):
            # Extract the ID, sequence, "+", and quality lines for each read
            read1_lines = interleaved_file.readlines()[i:i+4]
            interleaved_file.seek(0)
            read2_lines = interleaved_file.readlines()[i+4:i+8]
            interleaved_file.seek(0)
            # output files
            read1_file.writelines(read1_lines)
            read2_file.writelines(read2_lines)
```

These are my output files:

read1.fq

```
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTCTGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
```

read2.fq

```
@_5:1:7:9569:21200/2
GCACCATCATCACCGGTTCCGGGCAGCGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/1
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJJGHJJJJJJJIGGI
@_5:1:11:12099:7543/2
CAGAATGCCGTGGAACTGAAACGTATGGC
+
CCCFFFFFHH@HHJJJJIJJIHIJJIJJI
```